# Javascript/jquery Get Row Id on button click in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am beginner in javascript.So i am trying to get selected row id on button click.I am not sure i tried examples on internet however could not run code.

```
<tr>
 <input type="hidden" name="InterestID" id="InterestID" value="@info.InterestID" />

       <th>
           <input data-required="true" class="input-sm form-control datepicker" size="16" type="text" name="ValidDate" id="ValidDate" value="@info.ValidDate.ToShortDateString()" />
       </th>
       <th>
           <input class="form-control" data-required="true" name="Rate" id="Rate" value="@info.Rate" />
       </th>
       <th>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteInterest()">Delete</button>
       </th>
</tr>

function DeleteInterest(parameters) {
    alert("Delete Button clicked");
}
```

When i **click to "Delete" button** , i want to get **@info.InterestId** for selected row.So how can i get selected row id on "Delete" button click by using javascript/jquery ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: Your markup seems to be invalid. You should move the hidden input field to the `<th>` element.

Comment: may you please send your code example , i will try just now thanks and if works i wil laccept the best asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as below, As Ruben said if you not passing id into function then you can not get directly.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
       onclick="DeleteInterest('@info.InterestID')">Delete</button>

 function DeleteInterest(id) {
   alert("Delete Button clicked with id " + id);
 }
```

OR You can get as below, without change `HTML`

```
 function DeleteInterest() {
   alert("Delete Button clicked with id " + $("#InterestID").val());
 }
```

Comment: Is other option. Also without jQuery
change $("#InterestID").val() to document.getElementById('ValidDate').value

Comment: Yes Ruben, That is Pure Javascript option. But when Jquery is in question tag, So I proposed this answer

Comment: i always see id value "8" what is problem it is because of input position ?

Comment: Please check rendered HTML and compare the value

Comment: Probably you have duplicated id ValidDate, and javascript catch the first value.

Comment: I will suggest generate dynamic ID and get that in Javscript

Answer (score 2):

You can try to pass @info.InterestID to DeleteInterest:

Html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteInterest(@info.InterestID)">Delete</button>
```

And Javascript

```
function DeleteInterest(id) {
    alert("Delete Button clicked with id " + id);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would get the value dynamically:

```
var DeleteInterest = function(e) {
    alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("value")[0].value);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<tr>
 <input type="hidden" class="value" name="InterestID" id="InterestID" value="@info.InterestID" />
       <th>
           <input data-required="true" class="input-sm form-control datepicker" size="16" type="text" name="ValidDate" id="ValidDate" value="@info.ValidDate.ToShortDateString()" />
       </th>
       <th>
           <input class="form-control" data-required="true" name="Rate" id="Rate" value="@info.Rate" />
       </th>
       <th>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteInterest(this)">Delete</button>
       </th>
</tr>
```

I even consider more interesting having a hashmap in js matching the button with the value element instead of hidding it in the html, then, you should have:

```
var list = {<button_html_node_element>: '@info.InterestID'}
```

And then, your delete function:

```
var DeleteInterest = function(e) {
    alert(list[e]);
}
```